# math equation, problem with brackets

Tags: math-mode, equations, brackets

Hi i have a problem with "{}" brackets in my equation.

```
\begin{equation}
y= \alpha ^{- \int F_1(x)\,dx} \left { \ C- \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} F_2 (x) * \beta^{F_1 (x)dx} dx \right }
\end{equation}
```

I need this to looks like that: 
[image]

When i write this with brackets "[]" in code it works but i need this "{}" badly

instead of this i have an error :

```
Missing delimiter (. inserted).
<to be read again>
```

I don't know what is wrong in it, can someone help me with this?

Comment: Use `\times` instead of `*`, or forego it altogether, since multiplication will be assumed within the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `\lbrace` and `\rbrace` instead of `{` and `}`.

Comment: or `\{` and `\}`